# How to increase spacing between images in parbox?

Tags: spacing, graphics, boxes

I have the code

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{pifont, natbib, geometry, graphicx,hyperref,fleqn}
\usepackage{amssymb,float}

\usepackage{txfonts}
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\parbox{\textwidth}{%
 \centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example}

\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example}
}
\caption{bla}
\label{f1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which gives very close to what I want, except the four graphics are really close together. How can I increase the spacing between the graphics (though I still want them in the 2x2 configuration).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering

        \parbox{\textwidth}{%
            \centering

            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}\hfill
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}\vspace{10ex}


            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}\hfill
            \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image-a}
        }
        \caption{bla}
        \label{f1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ended up changing `\hfill` to `\hspace{}` (a command I found after asking the question) so I could have more control over the spacing.